base R: possible to redefine a color name or define a new one?
In a base R plot it is possible to specify a color as a number (which refers to the currently defined palette()), or a hex-string, or a name such as 'red', among those listed in colors().
Q1: Is it possible in base R to redefine some of the names in colors() to different hex values, for instance to make 'red' correspond to #EE6677? So that a call like
plot(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, col = 'red')

would yield the same output as
plot(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, col = '#EE6677')

(I'm very aware that this could break many things!)
Q2: Alternatively, is it possible to add and define new color names, for instance a string 'myred' that would correspond to #EE6677? So that a call like
plot(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, col = 'myred')

would yield the same output as
plot(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, col = '#EE6677')

(Note that what I'd like to achieve is different from what can be done by this answer to another question.)
Thank you!

If you don't quote the color name then you can assign myred <- '#EE6677' and then col = myred.

Thank you @RuiBarradas , that's a possibility. But I'm still curious to know if it's possible to redefine the builtin colours, so that, say, a plot(..., col='red') in an existing script would output the redefined red...

I am not sure, but I don't think you can redefine an already existing color. You also ask about defining a new color. Check this chart and package RColorBrewer.

No. This is translated by col2rgb() (e.g. col2rgb("lavender")), and the color table is hard-coded here.
For what it's worth I think this is the same as the X11 color name list, first defined in 1985.

Thank you Ben! Also for explaining why not – I was very curious about if/where things were hard-coded.
